# ASP.Net barcode reader show data

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a WCF service application that required to get the Barcode reader characters and show data of it on UI for user. My problem is that when I write data on textbox with keyboard is OK but when read from barcode reader overwrite it and show 3 times data in UI.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>سرویس و بارکد خوان</title>


    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setFocusToTextBox() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                document.getElementById('txtFirst').focus();

            });
           }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtFirst").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 17 || e.which == 74) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                console.log(e.which);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function JqueryAjaxCall(val) {
            $("#contentHolder").empty();
            $(".form-errors").empty();
              if (val != null && val.length === 20) {
                  document.getElementById("txtFirst").select();
                var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/jqueryAjaxCall") %>';
                var parameter = { "myVal": val}

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: pageUrl,
                    data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    success: function (data) {
                        onSuccess(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data, success, error) {
                        var myitems = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                        $(".form-errors").text(myitems.Message).show();
                    }
                });

       return false;
        }

   function onSuccess(data) {

            var items = data.d;
            var fragment = "<ul>"
            var BLNumber = items.BLNumber;
            var ContainerNumber = items.ContainerNumber;
            var Destination = items.Destination;
            var SerialNumberVerification = items.SerialNumberVerification;
            var TempPermission = items.TempPermission;
            var VehicleNumber = items.VehicleNumber;
            var VehicleType = items.VehicleType;
            var VoyageID = items.VoyageID;
            var value = new Date(parseInt(items.ExitDate.substr(6)));
            var ExitDate = value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
            var ExitPermissionNumber = items.ExitPermissionNumber;
            var myvalue = new Date(parseInt(items.SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionDate.substr(6)));
            var SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionDate = myvalue.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + myvalue.getDate() + "/" + myvalue.getFullYear();
            var SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionNumber = items.SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionNumber;

                fragment += "<li> " + " شماره بارنامه : " + BLNumber + " <br> "
                                    + " شماره کانتینر : " + ContainerNumber + " <br> "
                                    + " مسافت : " + Destination + " <br/> "
                                    + " شماره تائیدیه : " + SerialNumberVerification + " <br/> "
                                    + " شماره مجوز موقت : " + TempPermission + " <br/> "
                                    + " شماره وسیله نقلیه : " + VehicleNumber + " <br/> "
                                    + " نوع وسیله نقلیه : " + VehicleType + " <br/> "
                                    + " VoyageID : " + VoyageID + " <br/> "
                                    + " تاریخ خروج : " + ExitDate + " <br/> "
                                    + " شماره خروج : " + ExitPermissionNumber + " <br/> "
                                    + " تاریخ مجوز : " + SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionDate + " <br/> "
                                    + " شماره مجوز : " + SpecialZoneOrCustomPermissionNumber + " <br/> "
                                    + "</li>";

                $("#contentHolder").append(fragment);
            }  
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body onload="setFocusToTextBox();" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <form id="myForm" runat="server" dir="rtl" >
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div>
       <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="width: 80%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text="لطفا شماره سند را وارد نمائید : " Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                  <input type="text" id="txtFirst" onfocus="setFocusToTextBox"  onkeyup="return JqueryAjaxCall(this.value);" class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ede0dd"/>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <div id="contentHolder" >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <div class="form-errors" style="margin-right:-175%;font-style:oblique" dir="rtl" align="right"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
     <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <br />
     <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add code snippet  or example of the code you use

Comment: I think that problem is because of append. Presumably I do nat use append correctly.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

on this line code you call your ajax on every key click

```
 onkeyup="return JqueryAjaxCall(this.value);"
```

and so on each click you have data output, 3 times and maybe more, on each key press. Redesign your code so only when you are finish typing you make the render.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand it just now. problem was for this line of code

$("#contentHolder").append(fragment);

I add .empty() to that.

$("#contentHolder").empty().append(fragment);

I find it from this link

https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/jquery-html-youre-doing-it-wrong/